# bones causing weird scaling of the mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging

when i rotate a bone, it causes strange scaling outside of its weight painted area. As you see in the top imange, what the object should look like, but in the bottom imahe, it is deformed to make the arm half length.
*before*
[image: wat]
*after*
[image: wat]

Comment: Hard to see, you may turn X ray on, on the armature. But we can notice that the selected mesh is not scaled to 1. Try to apply scale on it (ctrl+A then scale).

Comment: PERFECT, applying the scale fixed it, thank you so much!